# Calculating the yearly interest?

Tags: decimal-expansion

i am doing a task where i met the following problem:

How can I calculate the yearly interest, with at least three decimals, when the monthly interest is 3.4%?

For me it seems hard to figure out a way to return three decimals in this case.
Sorry for may asking stupid.

Answer (score 1):

For one month you have $y_{n+1}=(1+r)y_n$, where $r=3.4\,\%=0.034$.
Therefore
$$y_{n+12}=(1+r)^{12}y_n=1.493641\ldots y_n=(1+0.493641)y_n,$$
therefore the yearly interest is $49.364\,\%$.